# How to determine if a grid row is new on edit in a Telerik MVC grid

Tags: telerik, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

I have a Telerik MVC grid that includes a boolean value, *CreateIncident*. For a new row, I want to set that value to true. For an edit, if the value is already true, I want to disable the checkbox. The Kendo UI apparently [added a method to determine if the row is new](http://www.telerik.com/forums/call-js-when-call-create-method), but the same call is not accessible in the MVC version. I can intercept the Insert and Update events in C#, but that's after they've clicked on the Save button. I can intercept the edit event in Javascript, which is where the above Kendo answer makes the call.

Alternately, if there is a better way to handle this, I'm open to suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer. Inside the javascript, I can do the following check:

```
// If this wasn't just created and Create Incident is checked, we already have a value for this, so disable it.
if (e.dataItem.CreateIncident == true && e.mode == 'edit') {
    $('#CreateIncident').attr("disabled", "disabled");
}
```

`e.mode` is set to 'insert' for new items and `edit` for older ones. Handy, that.

Answer (score 12):

The Actual Answer is

```
if (e.model.isNew())
```

so when isNew() is True then you have a new row else if it is False you are in edit Mode

Comment: Interesting. Unfortunately, that was two jobs ago, so I no longer have the code to test that.

Comment: I know but I think it will help others. At 1st i used your example and I thought it worked but it didn't because it was always true even if I add new row or edit a row. But with isNew() it worked perfectly.